# Поиск в MySQL по соответствию букв

Tags: php, mysql

Приветствую всех вошедших

Допустим я хочу в таблице mysql найти "Name" (Name = "Сергуньчегг")

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name`='".$name."'
```

Но сам нэйм может быть введен по разному

```
СеРгунЬчегГ
СЕргуНьчЕгг
```

Да и в базе тоже он может быть разный. Вот вопрос, как искать по соответствию букв? Ну и если велосипед уже придумали то как называется мое "по соответствию букв" в гугле?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE '%".$name."%'
```

Вроде так ;-)

Comment: @ua6xh, а что именно не так?

Comment: @Node_pro - уже всё так, коммент был написан когда было `name`='%...

Comment: @ua6xh, ясно, да я сразу вроде исправил)

Comment: оно самое!

Answer (score 2):

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE '%".$name."%'

Такой способ не ищет по соответствию букв. Т.е. если вы пишете

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE '%Vasya%' , то строки в которых содержится 'vasya' не попадут в выборку. Поэтому переводите данные при поиске в один регистр.

Например: SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE lower(`name`) LIKE lower('%Vasya%');

Теперь попадёт и 'VASYa' и 'vaSya' и все остальные комбинации регистров.

Answer (score 0):

`"SELECT * FROM table WHERE name` [`LIKE`](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/String_comparison_functions.html) `'%".$name."%'";`