# Запрос к MySQL с регистром букв

Tags: php, запрос, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток еще раз

Пару часов назад такое чудо было [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/259380/php-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B2-mysql-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2). У меня при поиске по таблице

```
//в запросе
WHERE `email`='admin@yandex.ru'
```

Вылезает результат admin@yandex.ru и Admin@yandex.ru. Хотя должно искать только 1 запись. Что как бы подразумевает, что дело в каких то настройках бд/таблицы. Собственно, что это за зверь, с чем его едят?

p.s. если есть MySql настройки проверяющие это дело и если нужно исправляющие, справку с направлением в гуголь выпишите

Comment: вы вместо WHERE лучше LIKE используйте. А если пользователю захочется ввести в поиск "admin@yand" - тогда ничего не найдет. а оно на самом деле есть

Comment: Чо за бред? :) Подумайте еще раз :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас поле в mysql какого типа? наверно чтонить типа utf8_general_ci? ci значит без учета регистра, сделайте его _cs и все :)

зыж чтобы не переделывать таблицу, можно задавать cs прямо в запросе:
select * from users where email collate utf8_general_cs = "admin@yandex.ru";

Comment: Во! Узнал больше чем хотел! Даже бед перекраивания таблицы можно!

Comment: just google :) and rtfm, its simple :)